# form_for submitting other submits too

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4

My form is to edit the table certificates. The form shows users based on attend and pass attributes. I have a button to update the certificates table with user pass and/or attend.

Right now it is running both attend and pass when I only want to update one at a time seperately. What could I place with @trained/@passed/@untrained/@unpassed to make it only run the code associated with the f.submit for the instance variable.

So `if form_for @passed` submit is submitted only run the if @passed. Something like `if @passed.nil? == false` Or is there a way to send an ID with the form_for ?

My Form:

```
<%= form_for @untrained, :url => certificates_path(@untrained) do |f| %>
  <p> Trained Users </p>
  <%= select_tag "certificate[user_id]", options_for_select(@current_trained.collect{|x| [x.name, x.id]}), {:multiple => :multiple} %>
  <%= f.submit "Un-Train", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>


<%= form_for @trained, :url => certificates_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
  <p> Non-Trained Users </p>
  <%= select_tag "certificate[user_id]", options_for_select(@non_trained.collect{|x| [x.name, x.id]}), {:multiple => :multiple} %>
  <%= f.submit "Train", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @unpassed, :url => certificates_path(@unpassed) do |f| %>
  <p> Certified Users </p>
  <%= select_tag "certificate[user_id]", options_for_select(@current_passed.collect{|x| [x.name, x.id]}), {:multiple => :multiple} %>
  <%= f.submit "Un-Certify", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>


<%= form_for @passed, :url => certificates_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
  <p> Non-Certified Users </p>
  <%= select_tag "certificate[user_id]", options_for_select(@non_passed.collect{|x| [x.name, x.id]}), {:multiple => :multiple} %>
  <%= f.submit "Certify", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The controller:

```
def create
if @trained = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id]).first
  @trained.update_attributes(attend: "Yes")
else
  @trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
  if @trained.save
        @trained.update_attributes(attend: "Yes")
  end
end

if @passed = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id]).first
  @passed.update_attributes(pass: "Yes")
else
  @passed = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
  if @passed.save
        @passed.update_attributes(pass: "Yes")
  end
end

redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path

end

def update
if @trained = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id])
@trained.first.update_attributes(attend: "No")
  redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path

elsif @untrained = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id])
@untrained.first.update_attributes(attend: "No")
  redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path
end

if @passed = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id])
@passed.first.update_attributes(pass: "No")
  redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path

elsif @unpassed = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id])
@unpassed.first.update_attributes(pass: "No")
  redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path
end
end
```

Comment: May be a hidden field in each form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Right now it is running both attend and pass when I only want to update one at a time seperately.*

Because there is no restriction on them. The restriction that you provided on `if` condition is just checking whether or not a certificate record exists. This will be true for both `trained` and `passed`.

Pass a *query parameter* to the create action which you can then use to identify if the form submitted was for `trained` or for `passed`. For example:

Update `form_for` for `@trained` and `@passed` as below:

```
<%= form_for @trained, :url => certificates_path(flag: :attend), :method => :post do |f| %>

<%= form_for @passed, :url => certificates_path(flag: :pass), :method => :post do |f| %>
```

Then in create action check for `params[:flag]`

For example:

Update `create` action as below:

```
def create
  @certificate = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id]).first

  if @certificate
    case params[:flag]
    when "attend"
      @certificate.update_attributes(attend: "Yes")
    when "pass"
      @certificate.update_attributes(pass: "Yes")
    end
  else
    @certificate = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
    if @certificate.save
      case params[:flag]
      when "attend"
        @certificate.update_attributes(attend: "Yes")
      when "pass"
        @certificate.update_attributes(pass: "Yes")
      end
    end
  end

  redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by action check? In my controller check the instance variable for the flag?

Comment: See the example in answer

Comment: +1 Your the best, let me work with this for a little.